# Declaring custom exception in Java

Tags: java, exception

when I try to catch this exception it gives me a compilation error message that says, "exception LinkedListException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement". What does this mean?

```
try {
        LList.Node someNode = list.nextNode(node);
        // We should not get here. 
        assertTrue(false);
    }
    catch ( LinkedListException ex) {
        // If we get here we are happy as it throw the exception
    }
```

Comment: it means you didn't call any code which throws `LinkedListException`, which I'd presume is a checked exception.

Comment: it means that `list.nextNode(node)` doesn't not throw that exception.

Comment: Does list.nextNode(node) have a 'throws LinkedListException' in the declaration?

Answer (score 2):

The exception must be thrown somewhere in your code using `throw` keyword.

For example,

The `ArithmeticException` is thrown some where deep inside the code . If you don't want to handle( just like how the person thought about writing `ArithmeticException`) you can bubble up like

```
void someMethod () throws Exception
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

The person who called this method have to handle it with `try`,`catch` , `finally` like we usually do for exceptions `IOException` etc.

So, if you want to throw your exception, add this `throw new LinkedListException()` some where in your try block where ever you want to raise an exception.

Answer (score 1):

If the exception is not a RuntimeException, then it must be declared (in the method signature `throws` clause). As such, the compiler can check if the code you call might throw this exception or not, and will not let you add a `catch` they will never be exercised.

If you are sure that this exception can be thrown somewhere deep down in that code, then it must have been caught and ignored or wrapped in another exception on the way. Or you are compiling against the wrong version of the class.