# Continue program after exception

Tags: java, exception, continue

OK, so I have this so far:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
class TooHighException extends Exception {}

class TooLowException extends Exception {}

class CorrectException extends Exception {}

public class HighLow {     
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TooLowException, TooHighException, CorrectException {

        Random random = new Random();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = random.nextInt(100);
        int guess = -1;
        while (guess != number) {
            System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
            guess = scanner.nextInt();
            if (guess < number) {
                throw new TooLowException();
            } else if (guess > number) {
                throw new TooHighException();
            } else {
                throw new CorrectException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is supposed to happen is the program picks a random number and the user is prompted to guess that number. It will then state if the guess is too high, too low, or correct. I know that `Exception`s are not supposed to be used this way but it is what is being asked for. The issue is when I get the `Exception` thrown it does not allow me to enter a new guess. Any help?

Comment: You're going to need a try/catch.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you mean? Not asking you to code it for me. This is what I get when I run it and make a guess: Enter 

    your guess: 99
    Exception in thread "main"      java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
 at TooHighException.<init>(HighLow.java:8)
 at HighLow.main(HighLow.java:43)
C:\Users\Roop\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `throw` to raise an exception but if you want to handle the exception you should use `try` and `catch` block. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40689115/4859791) to know what happens when you don't use `try` and `catch` block.

Use `try` block where there is possibility to occur an exception.

In your code, it is happening in `if-else if-else` block.

So,

```
while (guess != number) {
    System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
    guess = scanner.nextInt();
    try {
        if (guess < number) {
            throw new TooLowException();
        } else if (guess > number) {
            throw new TooHighException();
        } else {
            throw new CorrectException();
        }
    } // end the try block
 }
```

Now you want to handle the exception and not bubble up, so you need to use `catch` block immediately after `try` block.

So,

```
while (guess != number) {
    System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
    guess = scanner.nextInt();
    try {
        if (guess < number) {
            throw new TooLowException();
        } else if (guess > number) {
            throw new TooHighException();
        } else {
            throw new CorrectException();
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
    }
 }
```

When you are using `Exception`s created by you, it is a good thing to mention what is the exception is about like what is the cause when the exception is raised.

To do that, override `toString()` of `Exception` class. You don't have to write the message to user in `catch` block everytime if you are using your custom exception classes multiple times in your code.

---

Edit:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
class TooHighException extends Exception {
}
class TooLowException extends Exception {
}
class CorrectException extends Exception {
}
public class HighLow {
     /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws TooLowException
     * @throws TooHighException
     * @throws CorrectException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = random.nextInt(100);
        int guess = -1;
        while (guess != number) {
            System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
            guess = scanner.nextInt();
            try {
                if (guess < number) {
                    throw new TooLowException();
                } else if (guess > number) {
                    throw new TooHighException();
                } else {
                    throw new CorrectException();
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    } // end main
} // end class
```

Comment: When I try that and make a guess, I get the following: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.

I can guess again but it does not show my exception or tell me if it is too high or too low

Comment: @Sroop I have edited your code and updated the answer. Run the code and tell me. If it still throws, then print the stacktrace and edit your question to include the stack trace.

Comment: @Sroop You don't have to use `throws` in `main()` when you are handling the exceptions yourself. Read the answer which I have linked to understand where to use `throws`.

Answer (score 1):

You better check try/catch.

```
while(guess!=number){
try{
        System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
           guess = scanner.nextInt();
           if (guess < number) {
               throw new TooLowException();
           } else if (guess > number) {
               throw new TooHighException();
           } else {
               throw new CorrectException();
           }
    }



   catch(TooLowException ex){
System.out.println("Too low.");   
}
catch(TooHighException ex){
System.out.println("Too high.");   
}
catch(CorrectException ex){
System.out.println("Correct.");   
}
   finally{
       //This block always executes.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look in to using a try catch block instead of just throwing the exception.

```
try { 
    //This block throws the exception.
}
Catch(Exception e) {
      //This block will run next.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
try {
    if (guess < number) {
        throw new TooLowException(); 
    } else if (guess > number) {
        throw new TooHighException(); 
    } else { 
        throw new CorrectException(); 
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (guess != number) {
    System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
    guess = scanner.nextInt();
 try{ 
  if (guess < number) {
        throw new TooLowException();// when this line executes exception is thrown, anything written below this line will not run. If there is a catch block to catch this exception below try block, that will run next
    } else if (guess > number) {
        throw new TooHighException();
    } else {
        throw new CorrectException();
    }
 }
 catch(TooLowException e){
    //this will catch the exception you throw.
    //Usually we write e.printStacktrace() to get to know where the error occurred 
   // we also deallocate the allocated resources.
   //but in your case
   System.out.println("Too low");

 }
  catch(TooHighException e){

   System.out.println("Too high");

 }
  catch(CorrectException e){

   System.out.println("Correct");

 }
}
```

Comment: I think this is almost it, however, it no longer tells the user if it is too high or too low. It just allows another guess. Also, I should be seeing the exception as well, correct?

Comment: This is what I get when trying that:

    Enter your guess: 15
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
 at TooLowException.<init>(HighLow.java:22)
 at HighLow.main(HighLow.java:54)
C:\Users\Roop\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

Comment: does your class TooLowException extends Exception?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have the following problem.

Exceptions terminate the program execution except when they are caught by a try catch (see the other answers).
So to continue you would need to catch the exception and print something to notify the user of the outcome.
But if you do that you could just simply ommit the exception and print the outcome in the first place.

Comment: That would be the easiest way however, that is not what the professor wants. I had it that way in fact but she wants it to be done with exceptions.

Comment: Well, in that case you should already have all the examples you need.